# SSRS Leap Year Determination with DateAdd

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report that compares year over year changes for any date range within a year.  Thus, in my Reporting Services report, I have two parameters @StartDate and @EndDate that the user supplies.  I also have two hidden parameters (@PriorStartDate, @PriorEndDate) for the previous year with default values that are programatically determined using an expression such as this.

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Year,-1,Parameters!StartDate.Value)
```

I recently ran into a problem when 2/1/17-2/28/17 generated previous dates of 2/1/16-2/28/16.  Unfortunately there was a record on 2/29/16 that did not get picked up due to the leap year.  What's the most concise way to set my previous date while determining if a day should be added based upon leap year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the year is leap before calculate the previous year date. So for `@StartDate` it would be.

```
=IIF(
(((Parameters!StartDate.Value.Year - 1) Mod 4 = 0 and
(Parameters!StartDate.Value.Year - 1) Mod 100 <> 0) or
(Parameters!StartDate.Value.Year - 1) Mod 400 = 0) and
 Parameters!StartDate.Value.Month = 2 and Parameters!StartDate.Value.Day = 28,
Parameters!StartDate.Value.AddYears(-1).AddDays(1),
Parameters!StartDate.Value.AddYears(-1)
)
```

Replique the same solution for `@EndDate`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think that would work, just not as concise as I was hoping.  I found another solution that seems to work, but would like to run it by you and see if there are any issues.  What about subtracting 365 days instead of 1 year

Comment: @loganx80 if you substract 365 you will get the startdate + 1 day.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I guess that only works following a leap year.

Comment: Your solution returns 2/2/2016 when the date of 2/1/2017 is entered.  Should I also check for the day being 28 before adding a day?

Comment: @loganx80, you have to identify if StartDate or EndDate - 1 year is a leap year and if the month is 2 (february) and day is 28.

Comment: OK, I see that you modified the code.  Thanks.  I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

We use parameters in the data set that utilize this function.

Example

```
select @lastYearBegin =  dbo.ithc_DateAdd('YEAR', -1, @relativeFromDate)
select @lastYearEnd = dbo.ithc_DateAdd('YEAR', -1, @relativeToDate)
```

Function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ithc_DateAdd]
    (
      @datePart VARCHAR(5) ,
      @changValue INT ,
      @baseDate DATETIME
    )
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @returnDate DATETIME

        SELECT  @returnDate = CASE WHEN ( @baseDate = DATEADD(MM,
                                                              DATEDIFF(MM, -1,
                                                              @baseDate), 0)
                                          - 1
                                          AND( @datePart = 'YY' OR @datePart = 'YEAR')
                                        )
                                   THEN DATEADD(MM,
                                                DATEDIFF(mm, -1,
                                                         DATEADD(yy,
                                                              @changValue,
                                                              @baseDate)), 0)
                                        - 1
                                   WHEN @datePart = 'DD' OR @datePart = 'DAY'
                                   THEN DATEADD(DD, @changValue, @baseDate)
                                   WHEN @datePart = 'MM' OR @datePart = 'MONTH'
                                   THEN DATEADD(MM, @changValue, @baseDate)
                                   WHEN @datePart = 'YY' OR @datePart = 'YEAR'
                                   THEN DATEADD(YY, @changValue, @baseDate)
                              END

        RETURN @returnDate

    END
```